# Detect color bars ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is there a way to use ffmpeg (or even a linux command) to detect if the video being processed has actual content or just color bars?

This is my scenario: I have a system that uses BMD to perform RTMP streaming. That works nice, the only problem is BMD needs the specific mode configure to capture the input, otherwise it will only spit a video with color bars instead of the actual input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is capture a frame of the BMD color bars to an image, then do a difference mode blend with the stream which is then passed through a black frame detector.

Where the input stream and the color bars image match, ffmpeg will display readouts like this:

```
[Parsed_blackframe_1 @ 00000000034c67e0] frame:816 pblack:99 pts:417792 t:27.200000 type:P last_keyframe:640
```

**Step 1** Generate color bars image

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://example.com -vframes 1 colorbars.jpg
```

**Step 2** Analyze input stream

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://example.com -loop 1 -i colorbars.jpg -filter_complex \
      "[0:v][1:v]blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe" \
      -f null -
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will test it and let you know